# How to use Firestore withConverter in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I saw that recently the `cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0` update brought a new [`withConverter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/withConverter.html) functionality.

I want to use it to retrieve and pass my models from and to Firestore, but I am not quite sure how to do this with my existing code.

For example, how do I update the following code to use my custom models?

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').add({
  'length': 123,
  'rating': 9.7,
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Firestore types

To begin, starting with `2.0.0`, all Firestore **references** & **queries** are now **typed**. This means that `CollectionReference<T>`, `DocumentReference<T>`, and `Query<T>` now all have a *generic type parameter* `T`.

##### Default

By default (e.g. when calling `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection()`), this generic is **`Map<String, dynamic>`**. This means that (without calling `withConverter`), the data you pass and the data you receive is always of type `Map<String, dynamic>`.

#### `withConverter`

Now, you can make use of `withConverter` in various places in order to **change** this type:

- [`DocumentReference.withConverter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/withConverter.html):

```dart
final modelRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('models')
    .doc('123')
    .withConverter<Model>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
    );
```

- [`CollectionReference.withConverter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/withConverter.html):

```dart
final modelsRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('models').withConverter<Model>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
          toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
        );
```

- [`Query.withConverter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/withConverter.html):

```dart
final personsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('persons')
    .where('age', isGreaterThan: 0)
    .withConverter<Person>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Person.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
    );
```

---

What happens when calling `withConverter` is that the *generic type `T`* is set to your custom `Model` (e.g. `Person` in the last example). This means that every subsequent call on the document ref, collection ref, or on the query will all work with that type **instead of** `Map<String, dynamic>`.

##### Usage

The usage of the method is straight-forward:

- You pass a [`FromFirestore`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FromFirestore.html) function that converts a snapshot (with options) to your custom model.
- You pass a [`ToFirestore`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/ToFirestore.html) function that converts your model `T` (with options) back to a `Map<String, dynamic>`, i.e. Firestore-specific JSON data.

#### Example

Here is an example of using `withConverter` with a custom `Movie` model class (note that I am using [`freezed`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) because it is more readable):

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  // Create an instance of our model.
  const movie = Movie(length: 123, rating: 9.7);

  // Create an instance of a collection withConverter.
  final collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').withConverter(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
          );
  
  // Directly add our model to the collection.
  collection.add(movie);
  // Also works for subsequent calls.
  collection.doc('123').set(movie);

  // And also works for reads.
  final Movie movie2 = (await collection.doc('2').get()).data()!;
}

@freezed
class Movie with _$Movie {
  const factory Movie({
    required int length,
    required double rating,
  }) = _Movie;

  factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MovieFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: How to get the whole movies collection as a List<Movie> using this method?

Comment: Can you use it for Stream<DocumentSnapshot<T>>? I can not get my head around how to "turn the data of the snapshot into the model".

Comment: Why with DocumentReference you don't need to specify type, but with CollectionReference you have to? I was getting error, but only after saw this answer I noticed that specifying type with CollectionReference fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you've a model like this:

```dart
class Movie {
  final int length;
  final double rating;

  const Movie({required this.length, required this.rating});

  factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Movie(
        length: json['length'],
        rating: json['rating'],
      );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'length': length,
        'rating': rating,
      };
}
```

You can use `withConverter` like:

```dart
void main() async {
  final model = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('movies')
      .doc()
      .withConverter<Movie>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
    toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
  );

  final movie = Movie(length: 123, rating: 9.7);
  
  // Write operations
  await model.set(movie);
  await model.delete();
  await model.update(newMovie);

  // Read operation
  final fetchedMovie = (await model.get()).data();
}
```