# How to get documentId of firestore document when using withConverter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im reading the firestore flutter sdk documentation. It shows how to use a serializable class to automatically convert documents to objects with this example:

```
class Movie {
  Movie({required this.title, required this.genre});

  Movie.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
    : this(
        title: json['title']! as String,
        genre: json['genre']! as String,
      );

  final String title;
  final String genre;

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'genre': genre,
    };
  }
}
```

and then create a new document using the add function:

```
 await moviesRef.add(
    Movie(
      title: 'Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV)',
      genre: 'Sci-fi'
    ),
  );
```

How would I get the documentId after adding a new document or when querying?

Comment: Does this answer fits your needs : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079031/20239914

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve a behavior like this before, in Firebase Firestore, either you call `moviesRef.add()` then firebase will add a new document with a completely auto-generated uid, or if you're having a specific uid then you can just use the `moviesRef.doc(hereTheId).set()`.

However , the `moviesRef.add()` returns a `DocumentReference` which you can get from it the is like this example:

using then:

```
collection('students').add(/*...*/)
```

.then((val)=> print(val.documentID)});

using await/async:

```
final newDocument = await moviesRef.add(/*...*/);
print(newDocument.documentID);
```

You can also get a completely auto-generated uid before sending the request , then call `moviesRef.doc(hereTheId).set()` like this:

```
    final String id  = moviesRef.doc().id;
    moviesRef.doc(id).set(/*...*/)`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to use withConverter, so the add would return a movie object, instead of documentReference and I cant find a way to add id to the movie class

Comment: then did you tried the secondway I added

Comment: The second way wouldnt solve the following scenario: I query a collection, the user chooses a document and I need to save the id of this document in another document, as a reference. There is no obvious way to access documentid when using withConverter. I mean I found a few workarounds, I could add a second id as a key value pair or create a custom function to convert the raw data to an object so I could have id in it. It just feels that having an Id property in the model is a pretty important feature, I don’t understand why they would make it so complicated.

Comment: @Gwhyyy Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478208/can-you-store-a-reference-to-the-firestore-record-itself-when-creating-the-objec - it's a more concise use case, but may be of help to you

Answer (score 1):

I think we also need to manipulate the Ref to be able to use like you mentioned above with add method, which will get the `Future<DocumentReference> add(Movie data) Returns a DocumentReference with an auto-generated ID, after populating it with provided data.`

As shown in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) like following:

```
final moviesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').withConverter<Movie>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
    );
```

And while adding it you need added document id you can achieve it like this :

```
final moviesRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').withConverter<Movie>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
          );

  // Add a movie
  DocumentReference docreference = await moviesRef.add(
    Movie(title: 'Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV)', genre: 'Sci-fi'),
  );

  String id = docreference.id;

  debugPrint('documentId: $id'); // will give you the added Document documentId.
```

Comment: I found a solution using this method: using a late variable in the model class and then adding id manually layer, I just prefer to avoid using late because it’s not 100% safe code. But I just realized I wasn’t reading carefully, I hadn’t realized until now that snapshot.data was being manually passed as a parameter, if I instead pass snapshot itself I could probably get documentId from it, I will try it later.

Comment: @PortalGamesMais would you be so kind as to provide an example of your methodology? Perhaps as an answer to the question I posed over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478208/can-you-store-a-reference-to-the-firestore-record-itself-when-creating-the-objec -- although your method sounds hacky, I think it's probably the most elegant thing I can think of without them providing the DocID in the payload.