# Can you store a reference to the Firestore record itself when creating the object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The goal is to get a reference to the upstream DocumentReference which corresponds to this Customer for use in a query on another collection which references this document.

Is there a way to add a private variable `id` to this class which would correspond to the document, as if the Firestore path was `customer/id`? Effectively, what `cid` is in the query at the bottom.

```
class Customer {
  const Customer({
    required this.isAdmin,
  });

  final bool? isAdmin;

  Customer.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          isRepAdmin: json['is_rep_admin'] as bool?,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'is_admin': isAdmin,
      };
}

Query<Customer> customerQuery(bool criteria) {
  final dataRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customer').
    withConverter<Customer>(
      fromFirestore: (s, _) => Customer.fromJson(data),
      toFirestore: (o, _) => o.toJson());
  return dataRef.where('is_admin', isEqualTo: criteria);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can grab the document's reference from the `snapshot` in the `fromFirestore` part of `withConverter`. In my case, the most elegant way was to expand `fromJson` to take in the reference in addition to the json data payload.

```
  const Customer({
    required this.ref,
    required this.isAdmin,
  });

  final DocumentReference ref;
  final bool? isAdmin;

  Customer.fromJson(DocumentReference ref, Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          ref: ref,
          isRepAdmin: json['is_rep_admin'] as bool?,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        // IMPORTANT: do not convert 'id' back otherwise you'd write it to your data store
        'is_admin': isAdmin,
      };
}

Query<Customer> customerQuery(bool criteria) {
  final dataRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customer').
    withConverter<Customer>(
      fromFirestore: (s, _) => Customer.fromJson(s.reference, s.data()!}),
      toFirestore: (o, _) => o.toJson());
  return dataRef.where('is_admin', isEqualTo: criteria);
}
```

Now you can access the document's self reference with `customer.ref` just as how you would access `customer.isAdmin`.