# Flutter Expandable Grouped Listview

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview, expandable, grouped-list

I have an existing `GroupedListView` that I want to convert to (or replace with) an `Expandable` widget. My data source is from Firebase Firestore.

My code is extremely messy of all the "trying to figure it out" cases, so I will keep that as a last resort to keep the post as clean as possible. It kind of looks like this:

```
List<String> _headers = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> = [];
List finalList = [];
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot){
  for(final document in snapshot.docs){
    if(!_headers.contains(document.data()['headerDate'])){
      _headers.add(document.data()['headerDate']);
    }
  }
});

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot){
  for(headerItem in _headers){
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> tempData = [];
    for(final document in snapshot.docs){
      if(document.data()['headerDate'] == headerItem){
        tempData.add([{'name': document.data()['name'], 'idNo': document.data()['idNo'], document.data()['amount']});
      }
    }
    finalList.add([headerItem, tempData]);
  }
});
```

After this I am pretty much stuck and have no idea how to map the data under each `headerItem` to be displayed in an expandable group.

Is it safe to follow this structure or is there a possibility that I may get unordered results? Also, is there a cleaner way to write this code I currently have?

Thanks for your help with this!

**Edits:**

I am still not able to get this right. This is my implementation of how I understand it.

My code for the model:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class AttendanceData {
  static final _collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('attendance2').withConverter(
            fromFirestore: _fromFirestore,
            toFirestore: _toFirestore,
          );
  final String headerDate;
  final String tagName;
  final String tagId;
  final String workerType;
  final String teamName;
  final bool clockedIn;
  final String timeIn;
  final String timeOut;
  final String employeeId;

  AttendanceData(
      {required this.tagName,
      required this.tagId,
      required this.workerType,
      required this.teamName,
      required this.clockedIn,
      required this.timeIn,
      required this.timeOut,
      required this.employeeId,
      required this.headerDate});

  static AttendanceData _fromFirestore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
      SnapshotOptions? options,
      ) =>
      AttendanceData.fromSnapshot(snapshot);

  static Map<String, dynamic> _toFirestore(
    AttendanceData assignment,
    SetOptions? options,
  ) =>
      assignment.toFirestore();

    factory AttendanceData.fromSnapshot(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
  ) {
    final staffData = snapshot.data();
    return AttendanceData(
      headerDate: staffData?['headerDate'],
      tagName: staffData?['tag_name'],
      tagId: staffData?['tag_id'],
      workerType: staffData?['worker_type'],
      teamName: staffData?['team_name'],
      clockedIn: staffData?['clockedIn'],
      timeIn: staffData?['timeIn'],
      timeOut: staffData?['timeOut'],
      employeeId: staffData?['employeeId'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toFirestore() {
    return {
      'headerDate': headerDate,
      'tag_name': tagName,
      'tag_id': tagId,
      'worker_type': workerType,
      'team_name': teamName,
      'clockedIn': clockedIn,
      'timeIn': timeIn,
      'timeOut': timeOut,
      'employeeId': employeeId,
    };
  }

  static Stream<QuerySnapshot<AttendanceData>> snapshots() =>
      _collection.snapshots();

  Map<String, List<dynamic>> groupByHeaderDate(collectionData) {
    return groupBy(collectionData, (collection) => collection.headerDate);
  }
}
```

And then in the `StreamBuilder`

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: AttendanceData.snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return staffData.keys.map((collection) =>
      ExpansionTile(
        title: collection.headerDate,
        subtitle: collection.tagName
      )).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this: [How to use Firestore withConverter in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079030/how-to-use-firestore-withconverter-in-flutter)

It will give you an idea on how to construct a proper class with your data.

What I would do, is to first fetch the data with the converter, which then conveniently converts it into an object for you to use.

I would then use a groupBy method to group the data by a specific attribute (You can include this method in your object class).

I would then map this data into the expandables that you want.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Collection {
  static final _collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').withConverter(
            fromFirestore: _fromFirestore,
            toFirestore: _toFirestore,
          );
  final Date headerDate;
  final String name;
  etc...
    
  Collection({
    required this.headerDate,
    required this.name,
    etc...
  })

  static Collection _fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) =>
      Collection.fromSnapshot(snapshot);

  static Map<String, dynamic> _toFirestore(
    Collection assignment,
    SetOptions? options,
  ) =>
      assignment.toFirestore();

  factory Collection.fromSnapshot(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
  ) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return Collection(
      headerDate: DateTime.parse(data['headerDate']),
      name: data['name'],
      etc...
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toFirestore() {
    return {
      'headerDate': headerDate.toIso8601String,
      'name': name,
      etc...,
    };
  }

  Map<Date,List<dynamic>> groupByHeaderDate(Collection collectionData) {
    return groupBy(collectionData, (Collection collection) => collection.headerDate);
  }
}
```

And then you can simply use the data from groupByHeaderDate like so:

`data.keys.map((collection) => Expandable(..properties..)).toList()`

Comment: Thanks Lodewyk. This looks as if it will work, just a few questions. 1, I get a warning that `_collection` is not used in the class. 2, when adding `data.keys...` it throws an error "Undefined name 'data'". I placed your example in a class and the data section in the return body of the `StreamBuilder`. Am I doing this right or missing the mark here? 3, I also get an error "'groupBy' isn't defined for type 'Collection'".

Comment: You can add this to the model: 
`static Stream<QuerySnapshot<Collection>> snapshots() => _collection.snapshots();`

And then you can listen to the snapshots on the page with the expandable, using this info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471309/how-to-listen-for-document-changes-in-cloud-firestore-using-flutter . 

As for the groupBy, make sure you have collection in your pubspec.yaml as a dependency, and make sure to import the collections, like at the top of my code example.