# flutter firestore retrieve data

Tags: flutter, firebase

i want to retrieve data from firestore that has about 8000 docs, i have created method to get the docs data in a list then i created ListView to display my items but nothing showed...i created the same technique in other collections that has less docs like around 50 docs and it always works. so i don't know is the main problem is retrieving a large amount of docs ?

my code:

```
class FoodDetailsModel{
  late String name; late String caffeine; late String calcium;


  FoodDetailsModel({
    required this.name, required this.caffeine, required this.calcium,

  });

  FoodDetailsModel.fromJson(dynamic json)
  {
    name=json['name'];name=json['caffeine'];name=json['calcium'];

  }
  dynamic toMap()
  {
    return {
      'name':name, 'caffeine':caffeine, 'calcium':calcium,

    };
  }
}




void getFoodDetails()
{
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('nutrition')
      .get()
      .then((value){
        foodDetailsList = [];
        value.docs.forEach((element)
        {
          foodDetailsList.add(FoodDetailsModel.fromJson(element.data()));
        });
        emit(getFoodDetailsSuccussState());
  });
}







class FoodDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<NutritionCubit,LifeStates>(
      listener: (context,state){},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        NutritionCubit.get(context).getFoodDetails();
        return  Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Diets'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context,index) => buildFoodDetails(context,NutritionCubit.get(context).foodDetailsList[index]),
                  itemCount: NutritionCubit.get(context).foodDetailsList.length,
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => SizedBox(height: 20,),
              ),
            ],
          )
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget buildFoodDetails(context,FoodDetailsModel model)
{
  return Text(model.name);
}
```

how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow down the issue by debugging and checking to see if you are actually getting any data from firestore. I would have a look at your fromJson, as it does not have a return method. I suggest taking a look here on how to set up withConverter properly: [Flutter Expandable Grouped Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75775944/flutter-expandable-grouped-listview/75776074#75776074)

You can then check to see if your BlocConsumer actually retrieves the data by breakpointing in your ListView.

If you see the data in your ListView via a debugger, it might be an error with the way you are presenting the data.

If you have narrowed down where the problem presents, you can try and find the issue from there.