# Flutter withConverter fromJson/toJson syntax and methods for all Firestore types

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have spent an hour scouring the internet for how to use `withConverter` to marshall various Firestore v2 types into Flutter objects so that I can use them. It has been impossible to find how to do this for a List type (which ends up being passed down as a LinkedMap by Firestore). Can someone provide an example of how pair Array type with `withConverter` fromJson & toJson, and ideally for all Firestore types?

Comment: Seems there are a quite a few references - to `withConverter` both here on SO as well as the internet. Did you try searching? Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079030/how-to-use-firestore-withconverter-in-flutter) or maybe [this tutorial](https://dev.to/chinmaykb/working-with-firebase-database-made-easier-with-withconverter-473n)  or [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) or [tutorial](https://learnflutter.co/flutter-firestore-withconverter-for-data-storing-and-retreiving/)

Comment: @Jay - the comment [How to get the whole movies collection as a List<Movie> using this method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079030/how-to-use-firestore-withconverter-in-flutter#comment123697172_68079031) by Ahmad Khan
on [How to use Firestore withConverter in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079031/3744182) suggests the answer there isn't working for lists.

Comment: @Jay dbc already voiced the same frustration I had during my search. The examples I found are either outdated or did not seek to address complex cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very frustrating figuring this out, but I have a pretty comprehensive list of examples now, as seen below... if you encounter another variation and want to add it to the list, please do!

Note that there is some nuance in these based on how you define your document types in Firestore, but I hope this is illustrative enough. Most assume non-nullable to avoid unnecessary confusion.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserData {
  const UserData({
    required this.aString, // string
    required this.aNumber, // number
    required this.aBoolean, // boolean
    required this.aMapOfSimpleTypes, // map of simple types
    required this.aNullableMapOfComplexTypes, // map of complex types (also nullable to illustrate that minor case)
    required this.anArrayOfSimpleTypes, // array of simple types
    required this.anArrayOfComplexTypes, // array of complex types
    required this.aTimestamp, // timestamp
    required this.aGeopoint, // geopoint
    required this.aReference, // reference
  });

  final String aString;
  final int aNumber;
  final bool aBoolean;
  final Map<int, int> aMapOfSimpleTypes;
  final CustomType? aNullableMapOfComplexTypes;
  final List<String> anArrayOfSimpleTypes;
  final List<CustomType> anArrayOfComplexTypes;
  final Timestamp aTimestamp;
  final GeoPoint aGeopoint;
  final DocumentReference aReference;


  UserData.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          aString: json['aString']! as String,
          aNumber: json['aNumber']! as int,
          aBoolean: json['aBoolean']! as bool,
          aMapOfSimpleTypes: json['aMapOfSimpleTypes']! as Map<int, int>,
          aNullableMapOfComplexTypes: CustomType?.fromJson(json['aNullableMapOfComplexTypes'] as Map<String, Object?>),
          anArrayOfSimpleTypes: List<String>.from(json['anArrayOfSimpleTypes']! as List<dynamic>),
          anArrayOfComplexTypes: List<CustomType>.from((json['anArrayOfComplexTypes']! as List<dynamic>).map((json) => CustomType.fromJson(json))),
          aTimestamp: json['aTimestamp']! as Timestamp,
          aGeopoint: json['aGeopoint']! as GeoPoint,
          aReference: json['aReference']! as DocumentReference,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'aString': aString,
        'aNumber': aNumber,
        'aBoolean': aBoolean,
        'aMapOfSimpleTypes': aMapOfSimpleTypes,
        'aNullableMapOfComplexTypes': aNullableMapOfComplexTypes?.toJson() ?? "",
        'anArrayOfSimpleTypes': anArrayOfSimpleTypes,
        'anArrayOfComplexTypes': anArrayOfComplexTypes.map((o) => o.toJson()).toList(),
        'aTimestamp': aTimestamp,
        'aGeopoint': aGeopoint,
        'aReference': aReference,
      };
}

class CustomType {
  const CustomType({
    required this.moreData,
  });

  final String moreData;

  CustomType.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          moreData: json['moreData'] as String,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'data': moreData,
      };
}
```